# Meu SQL adiciona sempre 24 clique a cada acesso ao inves de 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho um script que conta as visitas em minhas páginas web e armazena do mysql, porém, ele está adicionando `24` cliques a cada acesso, ao invés de `1`.

O que está de errado com este código?

Vejam o script:

```
<?php
$idcategoria = 19;
     if (!empty($idcategoria)){
         $guiacomercial_cliques=mysqli_query($con,"Select cliques FROM 
         cliquesguia WHERE categoria =".$idcategoria);
         if (mysqli_num_rows($guiacomercial_cliques) > 0){
              $painel=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE cliquesguia SET cliques = 
              (cliques + 1) where categoria =".$idcategoria);
         }else{
            $painel=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cliquesguia (categoria, 
            cliques) VALUES (".$idcategoria.", '1')");
         }
     }
?>
```

Comment: Aproveite que você editou a pergunta e coloque a estrutura do banco de dados, descreva como está executando o código e como identificou que é somado 24.

Comment: Deixa eu consultar meus Buzios!!! Eles dizem que o problema é num tal de $q=@file_get_contents($ssite); que está no seu código  :)

Answer (score 0):

Tente apenas isso, sem o while:

```
<?php
     if (!empty($idcategoria)){
         $guiacomercial_cliques=mysqli_query($con,"Select cliques FROM 
         cliquesgc WHERE categoria =".$idcategoria);
         if (mysqli_num_rows($guiacomercial_cliques) > 0){
              $painel=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE cliquesgc SET cliques = 
              (cliques + 1) where categoria =".$idcategoria);
         }else{
            $painel=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cliquesgc (categoria, 
            cliques) VALUES (".$idcategoria.", '1')");
         }
     }
?>
```

Observações se `$idcategoria` é um inteiro, não há necessidade de se usar aspas. Elas são usadas apenas para string (texto).

Ainda teria como melhorar mais com a clausula `ON DUPLICATED KEY UPDATE` deixando muito mais leve e enxuto de código. Vou deixar um exemplo de funcionamento abaixo:

Se categoria é a **primary key** (PK) de sua tabela poderia fazer apenas isso:

```
<?php
     if (!empty($idcategoria)){
            $painel=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cliquesgc (categoria, 
            cliques) VALUES (".$idcategoria.", '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            cliques=(cliques+1);");
     }
?>
```

> Traduzindo, insira na tabela `cliquesgc` se não existir a categoria informada (**que deve ser a chave primária**), caso contrário se a categoria já existir (**Chave for duplicada**) some +1 ao campo cliques.

Comment: Amigo. continua adicionando 24

Comment: Pode postar o código inteiro? Altere a pergunta e poste todo o código.

Comment: Esse código é inteiro. A única coisa que ele verifica de fora é a variável ´$idcategoria´

Comment: O que pode fazer com que ele adicione `24`?

Comment: Se usou o que te passei não há como inserir 24, uma vez que botei 'cliques=cliques+1'; ou seja o valor que estiver no campo cliques soma +1. Aonde esse código esta dentro de um html?

Comment: Quando acesso o banco de dados para ver a soma dos cliques consta adição de 24 cliques a cada visita na pagina.

Comment: Eu posso colocar este script em qualquer das minhas páginas, e será adicionado 24 a cada acesso.

Comment: Categoria é chave primária de sua tabela?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62807/discussion-between-gladison-and-rafael-salomao).